# Cat keeps throwing up

Tags: cats

My kitty is 5 but every time she eats she throws up, there's no hair balls in the sick, she's very small for her age but not under weight, I'm very worried wot shall I do?

Comment: I am assuming you mean your cat is 5 years old.  How long has she been throwing up (days, years?) Have you changed her food recently?

Comment: Does she stuff her face when she eats? Some cats will get too excited and throw up after eating a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Take her to the vet right away.  Contrary to popular belief, it's not normal for a cat to throw up often.  She could have anything from gastro problems to food allergies to much more serious things.  There are emergency animal hospitals where you can take her.  You don't need to wait until Monday.  Go now.   I wish you and your kitty the best.

Answer (score 0):

I second that - she needs to be examined by a vet. This be anything, from a minor problem to a life threatening problem.

Our cats would have already been to the vets with the behavior and symptoms you are seeing.